# Add white page after table of contents before abstract

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

How can I add a white pages after the table of contents in order to have the abstract on a right page?

If I add

```
\clearpage
\newpage
```

I cannot get the white page added.

Ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In general you need place something on the page, like `\hbox{}` (aka `\null`), otherwise two page breaks in a row are ignored:

```
\clearpage\null\newpage
```

But actually you should use **`\cleardoublepage`** instead! It ensures that the next page is on a right page.

Comment: Just tried, exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 8):

If you equate a "right" page with an odd-numbered page, you have to issue `\cleardoublepage` after the table of contents *and* to make sure that your document is in `twoside` mode. (In `oneside` mode, LaTeX regards every page as "right" page, and the standard classes `article` and `report` that feature an `abstract` environment are `oneside` by default.)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\begin{document}

(The Toc)

\cleardoublepage

(The abstract)

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, my document is twoside, so cleardoublepage is what i need.